# I cant get Request Authentication Token - error invalid_grant

Tags: docusignapi

please help
I'm working on the docusign API but I can not move forward, I do not understand the documentation, at this moment I'm trying to get Request Authentication Token
with the following code:

```
<?php
// abrimos la sesión cURL

$datacodes = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQgAAAABAAYABwAA06V3LjTWSAgAAF8svy401kgCAP8Mq9QCVvVEoKzNp7QuGLAVAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAANGNlMjZiYWUtNWZjYS00YzYwLWIwODYtNTJmZDIyZWVhYmI0MAAA4Bq6LTTWSA.2wNculNmB4-AfW5D2iP58Ou9WmLauU-OH12ygvLFaYA6g1HQ4KpHATo7TWWm_lekHmUseEqIiyphn5U0aQ10zYS_FTkvZoeRK68cCTZg9mfw1s2jA3JexkDRx3j1MUbL5scW3NtNL5zmcVc7v5bj9Z9I2ns-vSJIOV_BZTc7izo2uV6kvdhaxrrpnj4BKZvWD9LElDUd-uHE4-jfuKWOwVx9P7gJZcSaDSgI9WkNXHv7HZHbz-5a9AMce1CSzBiucml5mFlNQn05YH3JjOufnP__cltFKqPgfO1KKNGksC_0AV2yHTWqnXb8lalOMdwN27VT3grMrR2i-MQhtY0SZw&state=a39fh23hnf23";

$ch = curl_init();

// definimos la URL a la que hacemos la petición
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token/");
// indicamos el tipo de petición: POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// definimos cada uno de los parámetros
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datacodes);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization: NGNlMjZiYWUtNWZjYS00YzYwLWIwODYtNTJmZDIyZWVhYmI0OmJiMzU1ODI0LTExNjktNGY5Ni04NDE1LTU5YjU5MzM2NWI0Yg=='
));



// recibimos la respuesta y la guardamos en una variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$remote_server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

// cerramos la sesión cURL
curl_close ($ch);

// hacemos lo que queramos con los datos recibidos
// por ejemplo, los mostramos
print_r($remote_server_output);
?>
```

But it does not work, I have

```
{
    error: "invalid_grant"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line here:

> "$datacodes ="grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVC......**&state=a39fh23hnf23**"

I noticed that the querystring parameter "state" is appended to the end of code <- try removing that to see if it works.

Also note that the authorization code is only good 2 mins.  If it takes longer, then you'll also receive the "invalid grant" message.